# Google cloud storage signed url how to generate sha256 hash in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, pycrypto

I need to use python3 and google cloud storage tgt. The example codes [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python) is written in python2 and I am trying to change the script so it works in python3.

In python 2, SHA256 works fine.

```
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as SHA256

def _Base64Sign(self, plaintext):
    """Signs and returns a base64-encoded SHA256 digest."""
    shahash = SHA256.new(plaintext)
```

but in python3, it doesn't seem to generate the same key.

```
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as SHA256
def _Base64Sign(self, plaintext):
        """Signs and returns a base64-encoded SHA256 digest."""
        t = plaintext.encode()
        shahash = SHA256.new(t)
        #print(shahash)
        signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(self.key)
        signature_bytes = signer.sign(shahash)
        return base64.b64encode(signature_bytes)
```

So my question is if plaintext.encode() is changing sha256 hash or it's just pycrypto has changed for python3. What can I do to generate the same key as python 2 version? Do I have to port python2  in python 3?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.